# JavaScript validation for datetime combination comparing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dates i want to throw an alert if astart date is less than enddate
format i use dd/mm/yyyy
time 24 hrs format :HH:MM:SS

```
var strt_date  = 31/03/2014 23:02:01;
var end_date  = 01/04/2014 05:02:05;

    if(Date.parse(strt_date) < Date.parse(end_date))
    {
        alert("End datetime Cannot Be Less Than start dateime");

        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following answer: [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

Essentially you create two date objects and you can compare them.

```
var start_date = new Date('31/03/2014 23:02:01');
var end_date = new Date('31/03/2014 23:02:01');
if (end_date < start_date) {
    alert("End datetime Cannot Be Less Than start dateime");

    return false;
}
```

(from reading the linked answer it is possible using the Date::gettime method for comparison purposes may be faster than the actual comparing of date objects)

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamps are not quoted as strings, which is throwing a syntax error, add single quotes to them:

```
var strt_date  = '31/03/2014 23:02:01';
var end_date  = '01/04/2014 05:02:05';

if((new Date(strt_date)).getTime() < (new Date(end_date)).getTime())
{
    alert("End datetime Cannot Be Less Than start dateime");

    return false;

}
```

Using `.getTime()` will compare as numbers, so you can determine if the start date has a greater number than the end date.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PPH6b/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the folowing format: `Date.parse("YEAR-MONTH-DAYTHOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS")`

```
var strt_date  = "2014-03-31T23:02:01";
var end_date  = "2014-04-01T05:02:05";

if(Date.parse(strt_date) < Date.parse(end_date))
{
    alert("End datetime Cannot Be Less Than start dateime");

    return false;

}
```